# About $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}= \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Without any reason, I suddenly realize that  I seemly  never see any theory about  the  series with two index. For example, what is the condition of following equation is  right?
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}= \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}
$$
I don't know how to deal it. So I check the book about series, but fail to find relative conference. So I ask here.

In fact, what I really want is a book about  series with interesting theory and the two index series, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Rudin (Theorem $8.3$):

Given a double sequence $\{a_{ij}\}$ and suppsoe that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty | a_{ij}|=b_i\;\;(i=1,2,3...) $$ and $\sum b_i$ converges. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \; \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \; \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$$

Comment: This sufficient condition is a special case of [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions).

Comment: Thanks your help. But I fail to understand the  proof of Theorem 8.3 of Rudin. In the proof, there is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}= \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$. I don't know why it is right. Could you tell me ? Thanks very much.